# Twitter Bootstrap with MVC padding between inputs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using MVC and bootstrap to create a website and have mostly been experimenting with it and found the following:

Whilst creating an in-line form in the navbar I noticed that the spacing between input elements were not correct. I think I figured out it was caused by the markup generated by the Razor engine there is no white space between the elements they are rendered next to each other without any spacing. But am not sure how to resolve it.

*Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPXgH/) for the invalid behaviour.*

### Razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("JsonLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "input-small", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserName) })
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "input-small", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Password) })
}
```

### Html

```
<form class="navbar-form">
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email"><input type="password"  class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
</form>
```

*Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e3rZ/) for the valid behaviour.*

### Html

```
<form class="navbar-form">
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
</form>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this? I am guessing I am missing something with bootstrap.
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you only get that behaviour if the input elements are the direct children of the form element.

try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("JsonLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form" }))
{
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "input-small", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserName) })
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "input-small", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Password) })
</div>
}
```

and you should get whitespace between the input elements.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it earlier, I used `<text></text>` instead, I couldn't post the answer as I am still a newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

The textboxes have no left or right margin on them so they should be right next to each other when there is no white space between the input elements. If there are white spaces, an inline-block element will render a 4px margin between elements.

To work around this you can either put the elements on the same line with no space as you have done, or float both elements to the left.

Comment: thanks I will see if I can get the Razor engine to create the white spaces as I do want the 4px margin.

Comment: As a workaround I changed the razor code by wrapping the html helpers in a `<text></text>` element.